# Adding a timestamp to a file, python subprocess linux

Tags: python, linux, timestamp, subprocess

I’m trying to take a picture with my `Raspicam` on my raspberry and adding a `timestamp` too each picture. The code that I use doesn’t however work. It gives me a syntax error at `.."+%H...`
I have mucked around in the code and was able too do it once, then tough the picture file didn’t receive any `timestamp` on it.

Does any one have any clue what im doing wrong?

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO, time, os, subprocess, random

gpout = subprocess.check_output("stamp=$(date "+%H%M%S")", stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,shell=True)

gpout = subprocess.check_output("raspistill -t 1 --output /home/pi/photobooth_images/Test${stamp}.jpg", stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are at least two issues:

- to use double quotes inside a Python string literal, you should escape them or use single quotes for the string literal:

  ```
  'stamp=$(date "+%H%M%S")'
  ```
- it is pointless to set `stamp` shell variable because `check_output()` call spawns its own shell i.e., `stamp` won't be defined in the second command where you are trying to use it

You could emulate `date "+%H%M%S"` in Python:

```
import time
from subprocess import check_output, STDOUT

timestamp = time.strftime('%H%M%S')
path = '/home/pi/photobooth_images/Test{stamp}.jpg'.format(stamp=timestamp)
gpout = check_output(["raspistill", "-t", "1", "--output", path], stderr=STDOUT)
```

Note: `shell=True` is not used.

You could also format an existing datetime object:

```
from datetime import datetime

path = '/path/to/Test{now:%H%M%S}.jpg'.format(now=datetime.now())
```

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax error is a basic lack of escaping the double quotes around the date format string. This is what is happening on the line which is causing the error:

```
gpout = subprocess.check_output("stamp=$(date "+%H%M%S")", stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,shell=True)
                                ^             ^       ^ ^
                    string begins    string ends      string begins and ends after )
```

You'll notice that the code colouring also signifies this.
There are two ways to include a literal double-quote in a string:

Either escape the literal double quote

```
check_output("stamp=$(date \"+%H%M%S\")" ...
```

or use single quotes for string delimiters

```
check_output('stamp=$(date "+%H%M%S")' ...
```